# Does the .data section gets loaded into memory?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm, portable-executable

I have attempted the following test to see if the .data section gets loaded into memory when the program is executed:

```
global _start

section .data
    arr times 99999999 DB 0xAF

section .text
_start:
    jmp _start ; prevent process from terminating
```

Assemble and link:

```
nasm -f win32 D:\file.asm
link D:\file.obj /OUT:D:\file.exe /ENTRY:start /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

I have executed the program, and the result was the following:

[image]

As you can see the program only occupied 276 KB of memory while it has an array with a size of 99999999 bytes!

Comment: Look up "demand paging".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paging model on most systems will cause the pages comprising the sections of the binary not requiring some kind of dynamic linking to only be loaded when they are accessed - Windows is no exception.  So, the .data section is memory-mapped as a binary file to your process memory space, but is not actually swapped in until you need it.   The process monitor only reports the memory actually in by default, although you can configure the columns to show all of the memory in the image, also.   There may also be compiler options you can use to change the paging behavior, and you can always remap the memory manually (perhaps locking it in) if you need.